QGIS: How to speed up loading of relation in forms
In QGIS I have two layers:

layer containing points (trees) that each have an specific ID
table contains all survey data. Each survey also contains the specific ID of the tree

I linked them via the settings -> relation
I want to display all past surveys of the tree in the Form, so I added it there.

This all works and looks like this:

But it takes some time to load. Is there any way to speed it up? My BA_ID (unique ID) field is currently stored as a string (due to the "_" and the dots), would it help to use an integer for this.
All tables are stored in a PostGIS-enabled PostgreSQL database.

The obvious question here is whether you have an index built on the lookup column. An integer is faster in join than a 20+ character string, mostly because it's only 4 bytes to compare (and they can be compared in one operation), but searches on an indexed string are likely to be faster than searches on an unindexed integer.

Ok, how can I check that and how can I built an index? When you say "lookup column" do you mean the field "BA_ID"?

It's a PostgreSQL database. pgAdmin will show the indexes, but there's a couple of other ways to get to that information as well.

Okay, but a spatial index is something different? Because oftentimes I read about spatial indexes, but I thought they are only used on tables with geometry, and my table "Kontrolle" has no geometry and only data stored in it.

It's a database. Indexes are indexes. Generally you can only use one at a time (per JOIN or WHERE), but a spatial index is just one kind of index (and only applicable to spatial columns)
